# .htaccess Rewrite Rule does not work correctly with index.php?path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi I have the following old url

```
www.domain.de/index.php?leistungen
```

and the new one is

```
www.domain.de/leistungen
```

I tried the following `RewriteRuile` like I did it millions of times.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?leistungen /leistungen/ [L,R=301]
```

But in this case I got the following result:

```
www.domain.de/path/?leistungen=
```

And it it routes to the root url

What is the issue in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```